# Node JS express server processes requestes from same browser synchrously?

Tags: node.js, api, express, asynchronous

I have two GET routers setup `/a` and `/b`.

I did `setInterval()` waiting for 5 seconds in PROMISE then response.

Next, I sent THREE requests, `/a` two times and `/b` once at the same time (approximately).

I got responses at the same time from `/a` and `/b` and the third response from `/a` after 5 seconds. These requests are sent in the same browser.

If I send two requests to `/a` from two different browsers, the responses come back at the same time.

WHY nodejs is blocking the requests that send the same API and from the same browser.

Requests to `/a` from the same browser is synchronous.
Requests to `/a` from different browsers are asynchronous.

HOW can I make the node server works asynchronously?

This is my code.

Routers:

```
router.get("/a", async function(req, res) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    res.send("This is A");
});

router.get("/b", async function(req, res) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    res.send("This is B");
});
```

Front-end: sending GET request on Chrome

```
<html>
    <header>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            let urlArray = ['http://localhost:3002/a','http://localhost:3002/a','http://localhost:3002/b'];
            function send(url) {
                axios.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
            for(i in urlArray) {
                console.log(urlArray[i]);
                send(urlArray[i]);
            }
        </script>
    </header>
</html>
```

Result:
[image: result1]

and
[image: result2]

Comment: What you are doing is not entirely clear. What you can be certain of is that every request you make is async in nature. And assuming you are not doing anything funny in the server side, node is not blocking anything. Maybe you are doing something wrong in the way you make the requests. Why dont you add your code.

Comment: Could you clarify your post and add some examples of your code?

Comment: Sorry, I just added my code.

Comment: Since when does Express support promises in middleware?  And, are you actually sure your browser isn't what's blocking?  (Your browser is probably using HTTP keep-alive, but since HTTP/1.1 pipelining was never all that reliable, it will only send one request at a time on that one connection.)

Comment: I think the Chrome is blocking the GET request. The node server is working asynchronously.